# pset8; cs50; javascript; when to use a named function and when to use an anonymous function in callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, cs50

In pset8, I have thought out 2 solutions for showing the information window when the user clicks on the marker.

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            showInfo(marker, articlesContent);
};
```

and

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', showInfo(marker, articlesContent));
```

why does the former/latter work or not work? I mean isn't showInfo also a function? **Then why do you need to come up with another anonymous function to call the other function?**

Apologies if this a newbie kind of mistake but I am completely new to Javascript and have been struggling for days for this pset. Would appreciate if someone could help me out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, you are passing the function as a parameter. In the second case, you are calling the function.

Example of the first case: https://jsfiddle.net/anqpby6s/

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert("Hello World!");
});
```

Notice the `alert` is called only when you click the button.

Example of the second case: https://jsfiddle.net/bwsps4b8/

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", alert("Hello World!"));
```

Notice the `alert` is called immediately when the code is run - that is **not** what you want.

You can research about Javascript Callbacks to go further into it, I found this in-depth article in a quick search: 
http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/